# Is it true that connecting PS/2 mouse to PS/2 keyboard socket damaged old IBM PCs?

Tags: keyboard, motherboard, mouse, ps2

Several years ago, my neighbor, who was once working at IBM in the "earlier" times (he's above 60 now), told me a story about a customer who reported that the motherboard of one of these old IBM PCs is damaged and they should examine the cause. It was in the times when the IBM 9595A was current, I believe.

As they examined the root of the problem, so the story goes on, it became clear that the customer connected a PS/2 keyboard to the PS/2 mouse socket. He said that it was possible to irreparably ruin a motherboard by doing that back then.

I was always really skeptic about that. Also because sockets weren't colored back then and it was probably very easy to make wrong connections. Also because my neighbor often made several subtle jokes.

Has someone experienced a similar case where this was really the cause? Is it still possible today?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Is there an actual issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: It's just a prevention of "not caring" in the future. I looked up that both PS/2 sockets have the same electrical wiring stuff, but the protocol layer differs. However, because of this, I wondered if the different protocol may "kill" the chip on the board somehow.

Comment: That shouldn't do it, but hot swapping (plugging/unplugging while powered on) the devices could -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port#Hardware_issues "They are not designed to be hot swappable ... **hot swapping can still potentially cause damage on older machines**, or machines with less robust port implementations."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never experienced that, in many years of accidentally swapping the keyboard and mouse in systems with two PS/2 ports. The only thing that goes wrong is you can't type anything, and moving the mouse might generate a few arbitrary keystrokes.